# Is continuous increasing function in $H^1([0,1])$

Tags: continuity, sobolev-spaces

Consider a function $f(x):[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $f(x)$ is continuous and increasing, is $f(x)$ in $H^1(\Omega)$, the Sobolev space with norm $\sqrt{\int_0^1 (|f(x)|^2 + |Df(x)|^2) dx}$?

Comment: If $f$ is the "Devil's staircase" then it doesn't have a weak derivative (however it has a distributional derivative)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you. But this function is only nondecreasing right? By ``increasing'' I mean strictly increasing.

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments, the [Devil's staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), $\mathcal D=\mathcal D(x)$ is a non-decreasing function with no weak derivative; therefore it cannot lie in any Sobolev space. Since the OP wants a function that is increasing, one can consider $f(x) := x + \mathcal D(x)$ instead.